# pandas calculate the counts and sum group by each category

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe:

```
    category    num1    num2    mark
1   A   2   2   0
2   B   3   3   1
3   C   4   2   2
4   C   3   5   2
5   D   6   8   0
6   E   7   5   1
7   D   8   1   1
```

i want to calculate the counts number for each category group by the mark(as the columns), like:

```
the counts:         

   catgory  mark_0  mark_1  mark_2
   A    1   0   0
   B    0   1   0
   C    0   0   2
   D    0   2   0
   E    0   1   0
```

another is calculate the sum of the number for each category group by the mark(as the columns), like:

```
the sum:            
    category numsum_0   numsum_1    numsum_2
       A    2   0   0
       B    0   3   0
       C    0   0   7
       D    0   14  0
       E    0   7   0
```

and my method is ：

```
df_z[df_z['mark']==0]['category'].value_counts()
df_z[df_z['mark']==0].groupby(['category'], sort=False).sum()
```

but it is inefficient

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df,index=['category'],columns=['mark'],aggfunc=len).fillna(0)
          num
mark        0    1    2
category
A         1.0  0.0  0.0
B         0.0  1.0  0.0
C         0.0  0.0  2.0
D         1.0  1.0  0.0
E         0.0  1.0  0.0

>>> pd.pivot_table(df,index=['category'],columns=['mark'],aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
          num
mark        0    1    2
category
A         2.0  0.0  0.0
B         0.0  3.0  0.0
C         0.0  0.0  7.0
D         6.0  8.0  0.0
E         0.0  7.0  0.0
```

Comment: can we change the 'nan' to 0?

Comment: if here is two num columns:num1 and num2,  can we caculate the  sum by designated num1 or num2？

Comment: TIL you can supply a list of functions as the `aggfunc` kwarg e.g. `pd.pivot_table(df,index=['category'],columns=['mark'],aggfunc=[len, np.sum]).fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `agg`.

```
idx_cols = ['category', 'mark']
agg_dict = {'num1': {'Sum': 'sum'}, 'num2': {'Count': 'count'}}

df.set_index(idx_cols).groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg(agg_dict).unstack()
```

[image]